# OSM all relevant keys and tags to extract Features for routable maps

Tags: openstreetmap, routing

My aim is to create a routable network layer with the openstreetmap editor from Esri. 
First of all, I need to know all relevant tags and keys for highways and cycleways to extract the data. Even pedestrian ways. 
At the wiki of openstreetmap, there is a list of all tags, but what about the keys. I cannot find a systematic overview.

Does anyone know (almost) all tags and features who should be considered?

Answer (score 1):

A good option is to take a look at [OSM2NetworkDataset](http://52north.org/communities/geoprocessing/osm2nds/). This application converts OpenStreetMap data so it can be used for network analyses in the ArcGIS extension Network Analyst.

OSM2NDS uses so-called ["parameter files" for routing](http://52north.org/communities/geoprocessing/osm2nds/configuration.html) (foot, bike & motorcar). Within these files attributes for routing are defined. They should be a good starting point.

Another valuable source could be the OpenStreetMap wiki and its [MapFeatures (for highways)](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features#Highway) section.